# Databricks change default catalog

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql, aws-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

It seems that when I am connecting to Databricks Warehouse, it is using the default catalog which is `hive_metastore`.
Is there a way to define unity catalog to be the default?

I know I can run the query

```
USE CATALOG MAIN
```

And then the current session will use `unity-catalog`.
But I am looking for a way that it will always be the default.
So, if the first query after login we will be

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MY_SCHEMA
```

The schema will be created inside the `main` catalog.

Answer (score 3):

Three ways to set the default catalog

#### Set workspace default catalog:

```bash
% databricks unity-catalog metastores assign --workspace-id 1234567890123456 \
                                             --metastore-id 12a345b6-9999-9de3-3456-e789f0a12b34 \
                                           --default-catalog-name my_catalog
```

### Set cluster (job) default catalog:

`spark.databricks.sql.initial.catalog.name my_catalog`

### Set BI Client default catalog:

#### JDBC:

add `ConnCatalog=my_catalog` to the JDBC connection URL.

#### ODBC:

```
[Databricks]
Driver=<path-to-driver>
Host=<server-hostname>
Port=443
HTTPPath=<http-path>
ThriftTransport=2
SSL=1
AuthMech=3
UID=token
PWD=<personal-access-token>
Catalog=my_catalog
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set: `spark.databricks.sql.initial.catalog.name`

But Databricks recommends keeping the default catalog as `hive_metastore`, because changing the default catalog can break existing data operations that depend on it.

https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/hive-metastore.html